# Понять логику исполнения цикла for

Tags: java, массивы

Все наступающего, у меня такой вопрос: я не могу понять логику данного цикла, а точнее его output.

```
int[] arr = {6, 3, 4, 2, 6, 1, 3, 5};
for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i = i + 2) {
      arr[i]--;
      System.out.println(arr[i]);
}
```

Output будет: `5,3,5,2`.
Почему снова выдает `5`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Выводятся нечетные элементы (которые с чётными индексами) минус 1:

6 - 1 = 5

4 - 1 = 3

6 - 1 = 5

3 - 1 = 2

Comment: Ахх.. Благодарю ;) Я почему - то сзади начал считать )